# show next prompt based on answering the current prompt in ODK

Tags: odk

I am new to ODK and I am trying to create an XForm in ODK and the following is the issue i am stuck in.

**PROBLEM:**

The user selects Gravel, Drainage or Unimproved from the first prompt. The next prompt is about the rating for the item selected in the previous prompt. Now I need to set rates 1 to 5 if Gravel is selected and 1 to 4 if any other is selected in the previous prompt.

**What I have done:**

I have set two prompts (Paser_Rates and Paser_Rates2), each has its own binding that the correct one is displayed based on the selected prompt.

```
<bind nodeset="/widgets/main_repeat/PaserRates" relevant="not(selected(../RoadType, 'gravel'))" type="select1"    required="true()" saveIncomplete="true()" />
<bind nodeset="/widgets/main_repeat/PaserRates2" relevant="selected(../RoadType, 'gravel')" type="select1"    required="true()" saveIncomplete="true()" />
```

This does not solve my problem because I am not supposed to have two prompts and I need to save the rating values in one column (Paser_Rates).

[image]

Please let me know what solution you have for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XForm terminology:**
The way to do this is to use itemsets with a secondary instance that contains your choice lists. Instead of relevants use an XPath predicate to determine which choices to show.

**XLSForm terminology**
This (and any other form) will be much easier if you use XLSForm to create your XForm. You need to create a [cascading select](http://xlsform.org/#cascade) and use a choice filter instead of a relevant to determine which choices to show.